# How to make D3 line hidden from start?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick, line, show-hide

So I currently have this graph with 2 lines on it. One blue line and one red. I have a function on the blue line which when clicked, it hides the red line. However I want the red line to be hidden on page load, then when you click the blue line... it shows the red line. Does someone know how to do this?

**Blue line:**

```
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("id", "blueLine")
    .attr("d", valueline(data))
    .on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = redLine.active ? false : true ,
          newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#redLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        redLine.active = active;
    });
```

**Red line:**

```
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .attr("id", "redLine")
    .attr("d", valueline2(data));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want red line initial to be hidden?

```
svg.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "red")
.attr("id", "redLine")
.attr("d", valueline2(data))
.style('opacity', 0);
```

Just add

```
.style('opacity', 0);
```

won't work?